# Passing pointer to pointer of array of structure from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

I want to pass pointer to pointer of an array of structure from C# to C++. With following code I only get the first element in c++, second and third element of the array is not passed. Why? Also, tried using StructureToPtr but didn't help. What I am doing wrong?

**C++ code**

```
 struct structure 
{
   short ps;

};
   __declspec(dllexport)short Testmethod(structure** aa)
    {
     if (aa!= 0 && aa[0]->ps == 26 && aa[1]->ps == 27)
     {          
        return 1;
      }    
      return  0;
    }
```

**C# code**

```
[DllImport("Wrapper.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public unsafe static extern short Testmethod(ref IntPtr a);

     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]           
     public struct SampleStructure
    {
       public short ps;

    };

 SampleStructure[] data= new SampleStructure[3] { new SampleStructure { ps = 26 }, new SampleStructure { ps = 27 }, new SampleStructure { ps = 28 } };
                        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                        IntPtr ptr = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();
                        ret = Testmethod(ref ptr);
```

I can't change c++ code, I don't have access to it. If change c++ code as either one of the following ways, it works. How can I make it without changing the c++ code?
**Updates:**

**Way 1:** works if I change the c++ code. But I can't change the C++ code. It's not my code.

**C++ Code**

```
__declspec(dllexport)short Testmethod(structure* aa)
```

**C# Code**

```
            fixed (SampleStructure* pArray = dataInformation)
            {
                ret = Testmethod(pArray);
            }
```

**Way 2:** works if I change the c++ code. But I can't change the C++ code. It's not my code.

**C++ Code**

```
__declspec(dllexport)short Testmethod(structure Getcsharpval[], int size)
```

**c# code**

```
 public unsafe static extern short Testmethod([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,SizeParamIndex=3)] SampleStructure[] array);
 SampleStructure[] data= new SampleStructure[3] { new SampleStructure { ps = 26 }, new SampleStructure { ps = 27 }, new SampleStructure { ps = 28 } };
 ret = Testmethod( data);
```

Comment: I don't have very much experience with writing methods suitable for pinvoke, but, have you tried changing the signature of the C++ method to `short Testmethod(structure* aa)`? Edit: Also, since you're passing a pointer, you should probably pass the length of the data as well.

Comment: Can you use C++/Cli in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved by creating the pointer to pointers of structures using the following code.

```
    [DllImport("Wrapper.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public unsafe static extern short Testmethod (SampleStructure** passstructurepointer);

     unsafe
            {
                fixed(SampleStructure** p2p = new SampleStructure*[3])
                {
                    for (short i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        var a = stackalloc SampleStructure[1];
                        a->ps = i;
                        p2p[i] = a;
                    }
                    var s= Testmethod(p2p);
                }
            }
```

Comment: No need for unsafe or stackalloc

Answer (score 0):

I think your c function have wrong proto.
Try:

```
_declspec(dllexport)short Testmethod(structure* aa)
{

    if (aa != 0
       && aa[0].ps == 26 && aa[1].ps == 27)

    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In your c# sample you have an array of struct. The array is a reference type, and you correct need to pin the memory. The array is a sequence in memory of struct that are value type (and don't need pin). So in the array you don't have pointer but direcly the struct.

Comment: I can't change c++ code, I don't have access to it. If change c++ code, it works. How can i make it without changing the c++ code? Please, refer the updated question

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `IntPtr[]` to the C++ code.

```
[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern short Testmethod(IntPtr[] aa)
```

Allocate an `IntPtr[]` array and populate it. Do so either by pinning each structure and using the address of the pinned object. Or do so with `Marshal.StructureToPtr`. If you use the latter, you have to deallocate the unmanaged memory after calling.